# Jenkins conditional parameters in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, parameters, build

I have set up a Jenkins job to run a bash script `script.sh` every day.

By default the script has to be run with no parameters so in Jenkins I added a String Parameter `PARAM` whose default value is empty and execute the script in the shell as

```
script.sh "$PARAM"
```

This way I can click on `Build with Parameters` add a string like `--param1=val1 --param2=val` and Jenkins would run the equivalent of:

```
script.sh --param1=val1 --param2=val
```

This works fine but then you have to remember all the possible parameters accepted by the script.

I would like to know if I can set String Parameters PARAM1 and PARAM2 whose value is empty by default and having Jenkins fill with --param1=val1 when PARAM1 is set to val1.

I know in the execute shell section I could write the command as:

```
script.sh $([ ! -z $PARAM1 ] && echo "--param1=$PARAM1") \
          $([ ! -z $PARAM2 ] && echo "--param2=$PARAM2")
```

but what I would really like to know is if there is some Jenkins plugin that could make this neater.

Comment: Assuming jenkins is setting `PARAM` in the environment normally then your original example will run `script.sh "--param1=val1 --param2=val` and not `script.sh --param1=val1 --param2=val` and those are **very** different things. That doesn't help with your goal I just thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks Etan I understand what you mean but I can assure you that it runs as script.ssh --param1=val1 --param2=val. I am not sure whether this might depend on the way I parse the argument or because Jenkins substitutes PARAM before saving the script in a tenporary file that is then run by bash...

Comment: If jenkins takes a script defined as `script.sh "$PARAM"` with a value of `PARAM` of `--param1=val1 --param2=val` as `script.sh --param1=val1 --param2=val` then that is **very** broken and likely makes it impossible to correctly quote/pass arguments with spaces, etc. Which, while possible, I find somewhat hard to believe.